# What is sql Type -10 (relating it Sql Server's nvarchar(max))

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, varcharmax

I've been investigating issues [with jtds' mis-reporting of sql server's `varchar(max)` and `nvarchar(max)` column types](https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3473108&group_id=33291&atid=407762) (which are the recommended replacement of `text` and `ntext`).

Between the inet, jtds, ms jdbc database drivers, the only consistent column definition is found using

```
rs = Connection.getMetaData().getColumns(null,null,tableName,columnName);
rs.next();
rs.getInt("SQL_DATA_TYPE");
```

(See link above for source etc)

Where [SQL_DATA_TYPE is "unused"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getColumns%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

For `varchar(max)` all drivers return -1 => `LONGVARCHAR`. However, for `nvarchar(max)` they all return -10. What type is this, and how is it standard?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I see; the java sql type constants derive from a sql standard somewhere. [The msdn page shows that the -10 is `SQLDMO_DTypeNText` (as opposed to -1`s`SQLDMO_DTypeText`)][1]. I can't find a page for Oracle, presumably because it's invested in java and so`java.sql.Types` is the reference for them.

Comment: In case this is what you were looking for.. Oracle java.sql.Types extensions: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/oraint.htm#g1076412

Comment: Not really. Oracle seems to have decided that there's no need to document the mapping to integer for these constants. Which is a bit strange, given their error codes.